# Update no banco de dados não está funcionando

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Meu `update` no banco não funciona, segue códigos:

**aluno.php**

```
<form method="post" action="?acao=save&id_aluno=<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <?php echo $pegaid; ?>
    <input type="text" name="ID" class="txt-medium bradius" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
    <input type="text" name="Nome_completo" class="txt-medium bradius" value="<?php echo $full_name; ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" value=" Salvar " class="btn-save-medium" />
</form>
```

**header.php**

```
if($_GET["acao"] == ("save")) {
     $startaction = 6;
}
```

**inserts.php**

```
include 'header.php';

  if($startaction == 6){
    if($acao == "save") {
      $pegaid = $_GET['id_aluno'];
            $pegaidpost = $_POST['ID'];
       $update_full_name = $_POST['Nome_completo'];
              $update_data = "UPDATE alunos SET Nome_completo = '$update_full_name' WHERE ID = '$pegaid'";
        if($update_data) {
          echo"<script> alert('Dados atualizados com sucesso'); </script>";
        } else {
          echo"<script> alert('Dados NÃO atualizados'); </script>";
        }
    }
}
```

Olhei no nome do campo no meu banco de dados, está `Nome_completo` normal, assim como esta no parametro `name="Nome_completo"`;

Comment: Está faltando todos os scripts de conexão com o Banco, que podem justamente estar causando o teu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SUGESTAO :**

- Primeiro : O ID é um valor inteiro ... Verifique se `'$pegaid'` lhe retona um carater ou um valor inteiro aqui : `"... WHERE ID = '$pegaid'"`.
- Segundo : A sua conexao com a BD esta bem feita ?

Comment: A conexão ao banco está normal, todas as outras partes do sistema funciona normalmente, login, logoff, pesquisa no banco, while

Comment: A minha variável $pegaid está me retornando um valor GET da url, está funcionando também pois os dados na tela só aparecem de acordo com esse ID, e os dados estão funcionando

Comment: @WilliamDePaula `"... WHERE ID = '$pegaid'"` tenta tirar o  ` '' ` no  ` '$pegaid'` e vê o que da !

Comment: Está retornando um numero inteiro normalmente a variável $pegaid

Comment: Agora deu certo, só tirei as aspas simples e atualizou no banco de dados, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda

Comment: @WilliamDePaula de nada mano !!

Comment: Eu gostaria de reabrir essa questão, pois aconteceu um outro problema, um dos dados estão sendo enviados que no caso é o Nome completo, mais quando eu edito o CPF da pessoa continua com problemas, não envia para o banco

Comment: @WilliamDePaula seria melhor você publicar uma outra questao explicando-se melhor ... !

Answer (score 0):

No teu código, além de não ter o código para a conexão, [mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-connect.php) não há o [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-query.php) que seria responsável por pegar tua variável `$update_data` e repassá-la como comando SQL para tua base.

Answer (score 0):

Tua conexão com o banco tá naquele header.php?

E nessa linha `if($update_data) {` deveria ser assim `if(mysql_query($update_data)) {`

Espero ter ajudado :)